# Appium Error (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, android, appium

I created a class in java to open a calculator on an emulated Android device. When I run the java application, the windows console displays a message saying: **Error: Could not find or load the main class br.ca.wcaquino.appium.CalculadoraTeste Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.ca.wcaquino.appium.CalculatorTest.**

In Eclipse, in the Package Explorer window, I noticed that my Maven project (CursoAppium) has an error message.

To find out what the error was, I went into **WINDOWS >> SHOW VIEW >> PROBLEMS** and Eclipse displayed the following error message: **Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: 'C: /Users/leand/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.9.6/ant-1.9.6.jar' in project 'CourseAppium' can not be read or not valid ZIP file.** The ant-1.9.6.jar file exists on my computer but I do not know why the error message. Below is the screens and my java code.

```
public class CalculadoraTeste {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver =  new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
```

}}

[image: Problems]
[image: Path ant-1.9.6.jar]
[image: Project Notice]